# I'm getting a rollup of the same value twice

Tags: sql-server

I have table `sellers` where I list every single one of my sellers, and I added the column `objective` recently.

```
id |name   | team_leader_id | team_leader | objective
--------------------------------------------------
1  |John   | 50             | Mark        | 30
2  |Jane   | 66             | Ryu         | 30
3  |Angela | 66             | Ryu         | 45
4  |Arthur | 190            | Carol       | 35
5  |Anthony| 20             | Adam        | 50
```

I have another table `sales` where I link my `sellers` table on `seller_id`.

```
sale_id |seller_id |seller_name |item
-------------------------------------
56879   |2         |Jane        |4P
23512   |2         |Jane        |3P
54827   |2         |Jane        |3P
12345   |5         |Anthony     |4P
55435   |4         |Arthur      |GSM
```

The query I'm trying is:

```
SELECT coalesce(seller.team_leader,'') team_leader,
        coalesce(sales.seller_name,'TOTAL') seller_name,
        seller.objective,
        count(*) as quantity
FROM sales
JOIN seller ON seller.id = sales.seller_id
WHERE seller.team_leader_id = 66
GROUP BY seller.team_leader, ROLLUP(sales.seller_name), seller.objective
```

I noticed that the result I'm getting a duplicate of every line that now has an objective.
I think the problem is because my `objective` column is new, and I'm joining my `sales` table with my `seller` table, it counts the records I had before creating the `objective` column separately.

So, my expected result would be

```
team_leader | seller_name | objective | quantity
------------------------------------------------
Ryu         | TOTAL       |           | 3
            | Jane        | 30        | 3
            | Angela      | 45        | 0
```

But this is what I'm getting

```
team_leader | seller_name | objective | quantity
------------------------------------------------
Ryu         | TOTAL       |           | 1
Ryu         | TOTAL       | 30        | 2
            | Jane        |           | 1
            | Jane        | 30        | 2
            | Angela      | 45        | 0
```

When the objective appears blank with Jane, it is a sale that she did before I added the `objective` column.

Comment: I think you want `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (seller.team_leader, sales.seller_name, seller.objective), (seller.team_leader)`

Comment: It removes everything I have on the `team_leader` column and adds 2 or 3 rows to everything else.

Comment: Perhaps you can be a bit clearer about exactly what groupings/rollups you want. There should be some combination of `GROUPING SETS` that works

Comment: I want to have one row being the total of sales made by my sellers, per team_leader, so there should only be one line show the total of the team, and 1 line per seller showing a count of  their sales, but since I added the `objective` column it messed everything up

Comment: `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (seller.team_leader), (sales.seller_name, seller.objective)` perhaps? "1 line per seller showing a count of their sales" is that their total, or still per `team_leader`?

Comment: it's the total of their own sales, on my example Jane should have 3, and the first line, where Ryu appears, should have the total of Jane + Angela

Comment: I also tried the `GROUPING SETS` you suggested and I'm getting an error `Incorrect syntax near ','.` on the second set

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following :

```
SELECT case when seller.name is null then max(seller.team_leader) else '' end as team_leader,
        isnull(seller.name,'TOTAL') seller_name,
        case when seller.name is null then '' else sum(seller.objective) end objective,
        count(sales.seller_id) as quantity
FROM seller
LEFT JOIN sales ON seller.id = sales.seller_id
WHERE seller.team_leader_id = 66
group by ROLLUP(seller.name)
order by team_leader desc, quantity desc
```

OR if you are okay with not using `ROLLUP`, you can get the exact same result using the following query.

```
;with cte as (
  SELECT max(team_leader) team_leader, 
    max(name) seller_name, 
    max(objective) objective, 
    count(seller_id) as quantity

  FROM seller
  LEFT JOIN sales ON seller.id = sales.seller_id
  WHERE seller.team_leader_id = 66
  GROUP BY seller.id 
)
SELECT team_leader, 'TOTAL' seller_name, '' objective, sum(quantity) quantity
FROM cte
GROUP BY team_leader
UNION ALL 
SELECT '', seller_name, objective, quantity 
FROM cte
```